# Lenovo thinkpad / Windows 7, low performance after running out of batter

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu, performance, thinkpad

I have Lenovo ThinkPad laptop with Windows 7 OS. If the battery happens to run out, after booting (on power cord) the performance is *very* low. When I open task manager, I can see the CPU usage spikes at 40-100%, then stabilizes at 5%, but spikes at 20% even for minimizing and maximizing the window. The processor is Core i7, and there's not even external processes running, only typical windows daemons. Even then the lag is too much even to do basic desktop operations painlessly.

Even rebooting computer doesn't solve the problem. Then, eventually the performance will come back on it's own. So what is causing the problem, and how to fix it instantly?

Comment: hmmm, seems like it's nearing the end of its life... when did you buy it?

Comment: I have not known this - hardware typically works or doesn't work!

Comment: Perhaps the battery gets warm when you charge it, and therefore the CPU is throttled?

Comment: Check the energy settings (via right-click on the battery symbol in the task bar). It might be that the laptop goes to energy save mode and throttles down the CPU whenever the battery falls below a certain level.

Comment: which process causes high cpu usage?